# Computing $\operatorname{MAJ}_n$ by $\operatorname{MAJ}_m$ in depth 2

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, circuit-complexity, boolean-functions, boolean-formulas, circuit-depth

Can the majority of $n$ bits be computed by a depth 2 formula all of whose gates compute the majority of $m$ bits where $m=O(n^c)$ for a constant $c<1$? Such a formula contains $m+1$ gates and $m^2$ leaves so $c$ must be at least $1/2$. I assume that the leaves can only be labeled by variables (without negations), but it would be also interesting to know the answer if we allow also negated variables and constants.

Two examples of such formulas are given below.

$n=7$, $m=5$:

[image]

$n=9$, $m=7$:
[image]

Comment: Just to clarify: the leaves are variables, or do you also allow constants or negative literals?

Comment: What does the function $m(n)$ measure? The smallest possible such $m$?

Comment: I'm slightly unclear about your model, see Emil's comment.  Moreover, did you want to exclude the construction achieving arbitrarily large $m = kn$ by applying majority to a $k$-times repeat of the $n$ inputs, then repeating this subformula $m$ times?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I've simplified the question as well as added two examples.

Comment: @Alexander: [this](http://www.thi.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/~jukna/ftp/thr.pdf) could be somehow related.

Comment: While this is likely not relevant for the asymptotic growth of $m$, I note there is a parity constraint: $\mathrm{MAJ}_m$-circuits with $m$ odd compute self-dual monotone functions, hence they can only express $\mathrm{MAJ}_n$ for $n$ odd.

Comment: Thank you, Stasys! Emil, yes, it does not seem to help estimating the asymptotic growth of $m$.